# AngularJS: How do I obtain the current option of ng-options in a custom filter?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angular-filters

I need to pass the current option value into the custom filter assigned to ng-options, but it always shows undefined.  I tried to use $index, but index is always zero.

I need someone way to determine the current ng-option iteration being filtered, so I can validate it in the filter and return true or false.

I know with ng-repeat, you can pass $event, but $event is not working for ng-options.  In addition, I have tried to use

NOTE: "prepared_attributes" are a list of product options which become filters on a product listings page.  This page here:  https://nestappeal.com/devsite/customcounter (stones tab)

Ultimately what it boils down to is, I need option.value to be available in builder.filter('zeroEvaluate'...

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, attribute) in productData.prepared_attributes" ng-if="key != 'remnant_min_width' && key != 'remnant_max_width' && key != 'remnant_min_depth' && key != 'remnant_max_depth' &&key != 'stone_min_width' && key != 'stone_max_width' && key != 'stone_min_depth' && key != 'stone_max_depth' && key != 'min_width_1' && key != 'min_width_2' && key != 'min_depth_sink' && key != 'sink_width' && key != 'sink_depth' && key != 'sink_material' && key != 'sink_type'">

    <label>

        <strong>{{key|underscoreless}}</strong>

            <select name="{{key}}" ng-model="$parent.$parent[key]" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in attribute | filter: {label: '!2 cm or 3 cm'} | zeroEvaluate:this:key:$index">

                <option value="">- {{key|underscoreless}} -</option>

            </select>

     </label>

</li>
```

---

```
var builder = angular.module('builder', []);
...    

builder.filter('zeroEvaluate', function () {
    return function (items, scope, filterKey, index) {
        var i = 0;
        angular.forEach(scope.$parent.$parent.filteredCollection, function(val, key){
            if(scope.dimensions(scope.stoneWidth, scope.stoneDepth, val)){
                if(val[filterKey] == scope.productData.prepared_attributes[filterKey][index].value){
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }
        });
        if(i>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }; });
```

Comment: You have some very unorthodox code and without a [mcve] will be hard to help

Comment: @charlietfl, I edited my post to add more details.